# BitArray creates bits in reverse order

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] bytes= ascii.GetBytes("ok");
```

At this point, if i debug and look at what is in `byte` variable, i get:

```
111 107
```

which is what i expect. "o" is 111 "k" is 107

Next,

```
BitArray bits = new BitArray(bytes);
```

At this point, if i debug and look at what is in `bits` variable, i get:

```
1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0
```

(the actual array has 'True' where 1 and 'False' where 0 above).

I was wondering why this was happening and why the bit array is not populated as

```
0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1
```

instead.

Comment: When you look at the byte[] then you see index 0, index 1, etc.  When you look at the BitArray then you see bit 0, bit 1, etc.  It is the *same order*.  You are just predisposed to see the bits in a byte written the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bit array is returning the bits (true or false) in the array order.  As previously stated, the order when in byte format is:

8765 4321

When iterating the array, the bits are returned in order:

1234 5678

It's a little confusing when doing the mental translation, but the ordering isn't trying to reproduce the original bytes.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. Even though it is kind of confusing that it does that.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xda43a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The first byte in the array represents bits 0 through 7, the second
>   byte represents bits 8 through 15, and so on. **The Least Significant
>   Bit of each byte represents the lowest index value**: " bytes [0] & 1"
>   represents bit 0, " bytes [0] & 2" represents bit 1, " bytes [0] & 4"
>   represents bit 2, and so on.

Comment: updated the question.  I understand that it is populating least significant bit first, but why would it to that.  Is there some simple way of showing it the other way around?  The way it prints it now is representing 246 214 to anyone who would read that binary.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

The short answer - it stores based on your processor.  If you are using an x86 or x64 processor, it stores as least significant first

Comment: ha! that was exactly where i was before posting this, and i figured it was a processor thing but wanted to mainly know if there was some easy way (that i didn't know about) to control which way they are populated

Comment: @thorkia the order of what is returned by an enumeration of BitArray does not depend upon the Endianness of the architecture. The Endianness defines how data are stored in memory.