# Why is my new BitArray initializing with the wrong value?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, byte, console-application, bit

**Background**

I have a console application here where the following things happen...

1. The user/operator enters a string of bits into the console i.e. "0101". - **Works**
2. The string of bits gets converted into a byte. - **Works**
3. The byte array gets reversed using my reverse method. - **Works**
4. I print out the reversed String in the console window. - **Doesn't Work**

My issue is with number 4 here. I create a bit array out of the newly reversed `reversedBits` value, and this is where things seem to go wrong. It's as if `reversedBitArray` is being initialized with the old/un-reversed `bits` value instead of `reversedBits`, as my output always seems to be the un-reversed String. This bug seems like it should be so trivial, the `reversedBits` is the correctly reversed value, so there is some issue with declaring the `reversedBitArray` but I can't figure out what. Below is all of my source code, including:

**The main console application.**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    BitArray reversedBitArray = null;
    String bitString = String.Empty;
    byte reversedBits = 0;
    byte bits = 0;

    // prompt the user to enter a string of bits
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a string of bits here: ");

    // wait for the user to enter the string of bits
    bitString = Console.ReadLine();

    // convert the string of bits into an integer
    bits = Convert.ToByte(bitString, 2);

    // reverse all of the bits
    reversedBits = ReverseBits(bits);

    // display the reversed bits
    Console.WriteLine("\nThe reversed bit string is...");
    reversedBitArray = new BitArray(new byte[] { reversedBits });
    foreach (bool value in reversedBitArray)
    {
        Console.Write(Convert.ToInt32(value));
    }

    // wait for the user to exit
    Console.WriteLine("\n\nPress any key to exit...");
    while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }

    // exit the console application
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

**The bit reversal method.**

```
static byte ReverseBits(byte x)
{
    BitArray myBitArray
    byte[] singleElementArray = null;
    int bitArrayMidPoint = 0;
    int bitArrayLength = 0;

    // get a bit array
    myBitArray = new BitArray(new byte[] { x });

    // get the length and mid-point
    bitArrayLength = myBitArray.Length;
    bitArrayMidPoint = (bitArrayLength / 2);

    // start the reversal
    for (int i = 0; i < bitArrayMidPoint; i++)
    {
        bool bit = myBitArray[i];
        myBitArray[i] = myBitArray[bitArrayLength - i - 1];
        myBitArray[bitArrayLength - i - 1] = bit;
    }

    // back to a byte
    singleElementArray = new byte[1];
    myBitArray.CopyTo(singleElementArray, 0);

    // return the reversed value
    return singleElementArray[0];
}
```

**Here is my sample output running in the console window.**

[image: Sample Problem Console Window]

Comment: You are just displaying the bits in the wrong order.  Normally you see the highest bit first but your foreach loop starts with the lowest bit.  Using foreach (bool value in bits) is the trivial workaround, hehe.

Comment: @HansPassant Haha, I've never written a foreach loop where it started at the back until now I guess!

Comment: Just use a reverse for loop, like this: `for (int i = bitArrayLength-1; i > -1; i--)`

Comment: @Pikoh why is all of this necessary, what's going on with the BitArray class?

Comment: I guess there is, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24462700/bitarray-creates-bits-in-reverse-order... But I didn't know that was the problem I was having at the time, or I would have just used the answer to that question. The way this manifested itself was interesting I think...

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the BitArray class, the problem is located between the chair and the keyboard :)

Comment: @HansPassant haha great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by other users, here is the fix I used that worked for me.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    BitArray reversedBitArray = null;
    String bitString = String.Empty;
    byte reversedBits = 0;
    byte bits = 0;

    // prompt the user to enter a string of bits
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a string of bits here: ");

    // wait for the user to enter the string of bits
    bitString = Console.ReadLine();

    // convert the string of bits into an integer
    bits = Convert.ToByte(bitString, 2);

    // reverse all of the bits
    reversedBits = ReverseBits(bits);

    // display the reversed bits
    Console.WriteLine("\nThe reversed bit string is...");
    reversedBitArray = new BitArray(new byte[] { reversedBits });
    for (int i = (reversedBitArray.Length - 1); i > 0; i--)
    {
        Console.Write(Convert.ToInt32(reversedBitArray[i]));
    }

    // wait for the user to exit
    Console.WriteLine("\n\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();

    // exit the console application
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

This simply prints the BitArray's values in the reverse order. Here is the new sample output.

[image: Sample Solution Console Window]